# Ansible - only last with_items being updated in file

Tags: ansible

Using blockinfile: which is using with_items from an exernal file. When I run the playbook I can see all itmes being processed but the resulting end file only has the last item updated.

Apologies, bit of a noob to this, so might be missing something obvious.

Tried various permutations

I have an external yaml config file with following contents - which is included as include_vars:

yaml props file:

```
ds_props:
 - prop: dataSource.initialSize=8
 - prop: dataSource.maxActive=50
 - prop: dataSource.maxIdle=20
 - prop: dataSource.minIdle=5
 - prop: dataSource.maxWait=1000
```

Ansible tasks:

```
- name: update DS settings
  blockinfile:
   path: /app.properties
   insertafter: "##### Data Source Properties"
   block: |
           "{{ item.prop }}"
  with_items: "{{ ds_props }}"
```

Expected:

```
##### Data Source Properties #####
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
dataSource.initialSize=8
dataSource.maxActive=50
dataSource.maxIdle=20
dataSource.minIdle=5
dataSource.maxWait=1000
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Actual:

```
##### Data Source Properties #####
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
dataSource.maxWait=1000
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for detailed response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blockinfile` is behaving exactly as designed: it adds a block of text to a target file, and will remove the matching block before adding a modified version.  So for every iteration of your loop, `blockinfile` is removing the block added by the previous iteration and adding a new one.

Given that you're adding single lines to the file, rather than a block, you're probably better off using the `lineinfile` module, as in:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ds_props:
      - prop: dataSource.initialSize=8
      - prop: dataSource.maxActive=50
      - prop: dataSource.maxIdle=20
      - prop: dataSource.minIdle=5
      - prop: dataSource.maxWait=1000

  tasks:
    - name: update DS settings using lineinfile
      lineinfile:
        path: /app.properties-line
        line: "{{ item.prop }}"
        insertafter: "##### Data Source Properties"
      with_items: "{{ ds_props }}"
```

While this works, it's still problematic: if you change the value of one of your properties, you'll end up with multiple entries in the file.  E.g, if we were to change `dataSource.maxWait` from `1000` to `2000`, we would end up with:

```
dataSource.maxWait=1000
dataSource.maxWait=2000
```

We can protect against that using the `regexp` option to the `lineinfile` module, like this:

```
- name: update DS settings using lineinfile
  lineinfile:
    path: /app.properties-line
    line: "{{ item.prop }}"
    insertafter: "##### Data Source Properties"
    regexp: "{{ item.prop.split('=')[0] }}"
  with_items: "{{ ds_props }}"
```

This will cause the module to remove any existing lines for the particular property before adding the new one.

Incidentally, you might want to consider slightly restructuring your data, using a dictionary rather than a list of "key=value" strings, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ds_props:
      dataSource.initialSize: 8
      dataSource.maxActive: 50
      dataSource.maxIdle: 20
      dataSource.minIdle: 5
      dataSource.maxWait: 1000
  tasks:
    - name: update DS settings using lineinfile
      lineinfile:
        path: /app.properties-line
        line: "{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}"
        insertafter: "##### Data Source Properties"
        regexp: "{{ item.key }}"
      with_items: "{{ ds_props|dict2items }}"
```

And lastly, rather than using `lineinfile` or `blockinfile`, you might want to consider using ansible's `template` module to create your `/app.properties` file rather than trying to edit it.

Answer (score 3):

[`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) uses a `marker` to keep track of the blocks it manages in a file. By default, this marker is `ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK`.

What happens in your case since you use the default marker is that a block is created after the line "##### Data Source Properties" for the first item then edited for the next items.

One solution would be to change the marker for each item. An other is to use lineinfile as reported by @Larsk

I would prefer in this case creating the full block at once:

```
- name: update DS settings
  blockinfile:
   path: /app.properties
   insertafter: "##### Data Source Properties"
   marker: "Custom ds props - ansible managed"
   block: "{{ ds_props | json_query('[].prop') | join('\n') }}"
```

If your intent is to do more complicated stuff with your config file, follow @Larsk advice and use a template.